# Is there a way to control BottomSheetDialogFragment's visibility behind the navigation bar?

Tags: material-components-android

Is there any way to control BottomSheetDialogFragment show behind the navigation bar?

My Activity is fullscreen with translucent navication bar, which works fine but after show a bottom sheet dialog.

so is there any way to control BottomSheetDialogFragment show behind the navigation bar?

[image: screenshot]

- Tried set `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000000</item>` not work
- Tried set `<item name="enableEdgeToEdge">true</item>` and `<item name="paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets">false</item>` not work